# How to access aspx page and HiddenField which is defined on that page in unit test method?

Tags: asp.net, c#-2.0

I want to access aspx page and HiddenField in Unit Test method.
the aspx page and HiddenField i need to pass as parameter to another method which is defined in .cs file.Is it possible?

Comment: Can you please,elaborate your qn.

Answer (score 0):

Session can be used for storing entire page content and hidden field can be passed as parameter to unit test method.